# How to install a certificate on Android TV?

Tags: security, android-tv

I've installed certificates (especially the FiddlerRootCA) on several android devices already, since it has a security section in the menus.

On Android TV on the other hand, I was not able to find anything in the settings, altough I went through them? I would like to install the certificate here on my Android TV stick, on which I have adb root access to.

How can I install a certificate on my Android TV?

Comment: On regular Android devices installing Fiddler Root CA certificate is useless, as Android and nearly every app just ignores user installed root certificates. Not sure if Android TV also works this way, but I would assume so. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978 for details.

Comment: @Robert the correct and complete statement is:  "*Apps that target API Level 24 and above no longer trust user or admin-added CAs for secure connections, by default.*" "*But app developers can choose to let their apps work with manually added CA certificates*" by adding `<certificates src="user" />` to [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config). So if the app is targeting Android version below Nougat or if it deliberately makes use of user certificates, it's definitely gonna work.

Comment: @IrfanLatif But Google does no accept apps with a lower than maximum `targetSdkVersion` for Google Play Store. Therefore in Play Store only apps that have not been updated for about more than 3 years can have a targetSdkVersion lower than 24. But of course it may apply if that app was side-loaded.